# Resize a UILabel so it looks the same on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to adapt an existing iPhone only app to support the iPhone 6's as well as iPads. I do not want the app layout to change I just want it to resize to fit the various devices.

A number of UILabels on screen have updatable content which is truncated with an ellipsis if too long.

[image: three sizes of resizable label on screens]

I would love to be able to do this with autolayout in a storyboard but if code is the only way to do it then so be it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don`t want use auto layout in code. You can ask for the screen size: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size , and use this to define the label dimensions. e. g. CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size; UILabel *firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 35, size.widh - 50, 0.05*size.height)];

Comment: No idea why I got a down-vote? Thanks for the response @Onik IV and I have nothing against using autolayout in code - I was hoping to be able to do it with autolayout in a storyboard as that is my preferred method of laying stuff out. I thought this would be an obvious use-case for autolayout but appear to have been mistaken.

Comment: Can whoever down votes this please explain why? Seems a bit strange...

Comment: Because you're missing the point of auto layout and universal apps.

Comment: Wasn't me. But I think you should rephrase to combat the misunderstanding that you are only taking about the frame of the label. I had to take a second look at the image (which I glossed over at first) to understand you wanted to scale the text relative to screen size. Or you might be offending people who think ui layout *should* change for iPad and don't like that you want to just scale.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Filip but I am developing for a specific use case. I am not missing the point of autolayout or universal apps if my users are looking specifically for a scaled up version of what they have on their iPhones. I would have an insurrection on my hands if I forced my users (the majority of whom are using my iPhone app on their iPads) to have to squint at their iPads. I have had many users emailing to tell me they have purchased an iPad to use my app as it is easier to read on stage than the competitors. I do have many decades of commercial UI design experience as well.

Comment: And many thanks to you too @Sterling for your input and your suggestion below. I really was just hoping, after spending a few hours on this, that someone had an insight into autolayout that eluded me.

Comment: @amergin If you want use Autolayout by code is easy to learn (here is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html). In fact, there are a couple of methods. (and both do the same work in a different manner). In my experience the easy way to learn is make a complete viewController (and view) by storyboard and test until get the same by code. About down-vote it´s something I'll never understand, in a place like that to help and get helping, there are some people than quickly make a down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically set a font size as a fraction of screen size. Like so:

```
/* 
 * Screen size is orientation dependent on iOS 8, so take the shortest
 * dimension as a rough measure of screen size
 */
CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
CGFloat sizeFactor = (size.width < size.height) ? size.width : size.height;

label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:sizeFactor / 16.f];
```

Comment: Thanks @sterling, if I end up having to do this in code this does seem an elegant way of doing it.

Comment: I'll go with this one with a bit of editing - thanks @sterling. Would have liked to get it done in the storyboard because I have a load UILabels to do but I'll just create a subclass and use that instead.